# Finding a convergent majorant series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, trigonometric-series

I have a series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{n^3} \cos(nt) - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} \sin(nt) \right)
$$
and I have to find a majorant series to this series.

The convergent majorant series I was supposed to find is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{n^3} + \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} \right).
$$
however, I don't exactly get why.

I thought that $\frac{1}{n^3}$ is also a convergent majorant series.

I know that the first term $\frac{1}{n^3} \cos(nt)$ is always less than or equal to $\frac{1}{n^3}$ and subtracting the second term $\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} \sin(nt)$ will only make it smaller, so why doesn't this inequality hold:
$$
|f_n(t)| = |\frac{1}{n^3} \cos(nt) - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} \sin(nt)| \leq \frac{1}{n^3}
$$

Comment: it's the triangle inequality and a basic fact about sine and cosine.

Comment: $\sin (nt)$ can have the opposite sign of $\cos (nt)$, and then $\lvert f_n(t)\rvert = \frac{1}{n^3} \lvert \cos (nt)\rvert + \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\lvert\sin (nt)\rvert$, which can be larger than $\frac{1}{n^3}$. Also, if $\lvert\sin (nt)\rvert$ is close to $1$, $\lvert f_n(t)\rvert$ is close to $\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. You may use
$$
|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|,\qquad a,b \in \mathbb{R},
$$ giving, for $n=1,2,3 \cdots,$
$$
\left| \frac{1}{n^3} \cos(nt) - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} \sin(nt) \right|\leq \left| \frac{1}{n^3} \cos(nt)\right|+\left| - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} \sin(nt)\right|\leq \frac{1}{n^3} + \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}
$$ since $|\cos (nt)|\leq 1$ and $|\sin (nt)|\leq 1$.